# "Set out" or "hit the road"

Tags: idioms

I need to communicate the time we need to leave a house in order to catch a train, should I say "We should set out at 18:15" or "We should hit the road at 18:15". Does it have the same meaning? What native speaker prefer?

Comment: It depends entirely on context. To *hit the road* is an extremely informal / colloquial usage, that wouldn't always be appropriate anyway. Besides which not everyone would be happy to extend the (highly figurative) sense if the planned journey were to be by *train*, for example. But note that ***set out / set off*** would never be "inappropriate", so if you're not sure of your context, you should definitely stick to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **set out
>
>   set off
>
>   hit the road
>
>   be on our way
>
>   be on the road
>
>   leave
>
>   get going**

are all expressions to say when to **start off** on a journey and have the same meanings

After one of these expressions, the designated time is given **by** *a time* or some other appropriate preposition: **at**, **before**, **after**

> We should **leave by** 10:00
>   We should **be on our way** after lunch
>   We can **leave before breakfast**
>   We need to **leave just after the show** to make our train

Most usual is to use a simple **leave**

> I will **leave** at 6:00
>   I'll **be gone** before you wake up